# How to perform a combined/parallel scaling and translation animation in JavaFX 8

Tags: java, animation, javafx-8

I just recently started to play around with Java FX and really like it. I didn’t read any books or in depth tutorials about it yet so this question is maybe very simple to answer.

I want to zoom in on an *ImageView* and show the user a specific region of an *Image* in case when he clicks at a certain area of the image. To be more precise take a look at the following Image:

[image]

(if the image is too small, [here is a bigger version](http://f.666kb.com/i/crtczazyvpv2xirs2.jpg))

**(A)** shows the full image I am using (world-map.jpg, size: 4.000px X 3.000px)

**(1)** shows the Stage I am showing the user. I performed some initial scaling and translation to the ImageView object so that the view is more centered on Europe and Africa. The marked region is an additional Element with an attached Event handler (not in my code)

**(2)** shows the **result I got** after performing my ParallelTransition

**(3)** shows the **result I want** to get

What happens when I perform my ParallelTransition is that the ImageView gets zoomed in properly but also translated to the bottom right corner of the Image. What did I do wrong?

Here is my JavaFX Application code:

```
@Override
  public void start(final Stage stage)
  {

    // our root group
    final Group g = new Group();

    // load image
    ImageView im = new ImageView();
    // using a helper method to load external resource
    Image img = FileUtils.loadImage(R.imageWorldMap);
    im.setImage(img);
    g.getChildren().add(im);

    // translate to center view on europe and africa
    Translate t = new Translate();
    t.setX(-300);
    t.setY(-200);
    im.getTransforms().add(t);

    // zoom out because source image is huge
    Scale scale = new Scale();
    scale.setX(.3);
    scale.setY(.3);
    im.getTransforms().add(scale);

    // create scene and show stage
    final Scene s = new Scene(g, 640, 480);
    stage.setScene(s);
    stage.show();

    // code below is normally inside an event handler 
    // but for simplicity reason and testing its like that now

    // move europe to the center
    TranslateTransition translateTransition =
            new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), im);

    translateTransition.setToX(1100); // 3300
    translateTransition.setToY(900); // 2700

    // scale in europe
    ScaleTransition scaleTransition =
            new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(2000), im);
    scaleTransition.setToX(3f);
    scaleTransition.setToY(3f);

    // create parallel translation
    ParallelTransition parallelTransition = new ParallelTransition();
    parallelTransition.getChildren().addAll(
            scaleTransition
            , translateTransition
    );

    parallelTransition.play();

  }
```

I played around a bit with coordinates to get better results, and I did, but I would like to understand how to pragmatically get this task done.

As a side question, can you recommend (by your experience) a book for Java FX 8.

Tech I use: Win7, Java8, JavaFX8

Answer (score 0):

I'd refer to the examples... [Demos](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) under the javafx ones there is a project that does what you want i believe.. MandrelBot ... src is in same package..